# Controller do angularjs não funciona direito

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, angular-material

estou dando uma estudada básica em como criar telas usando Angularjs e Material, tudo indo bem até eu precisar do controller, parece que o $scope não está funcionando, coloquei um console.log no inicio do controller e ele imprime o texto, mas os valores setados para $scope não são aplicados na tela e as funções chamadas usando ng-click também não são executadas.

```
<body ng-app="App" layout="column" ng-controller="PageController as pc">

<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <md-button class="menu" ng-click="pc.toggleMenu()">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </md-button>
    <h1>Angular Material</h1>
</md-toolbar>

<div class="container" layout="row" style="min-height: 100%;">
    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" class="md-whiteframe-4dp" flex="20" md-component-id="left">
        {{pc.sidenav}}
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content id="content" flex>
        <md-button class="md-raised">BUTTON</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">BUTTON</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-accent">BUTTON</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-warn">BUTTON</md-button>
    </md-content>
</div>  
<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">    

angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('PageController', function($scope, $mdSidenav){
    console.log('Aparece no console!');

    $scope.sidenav = "Sidenav";
    $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
        console.log('toggleMenu');
        $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
    };
})
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('blue')
        .accentPalette('orange')
        .warnPalette('deep-orange').dark();
});    
</script>

</body>
```

O .config e o console.log() no .controller funcionam, só o $scope que não esta funcionando.

Comment: Só há necessidade de alias "pc" quando há mais de um controle na view. Além disso vc incorporou seu script dentro do elemento onde vc está o chamando? Coloque seu script fora do body, num arquivo a parte. E chame o ng-app no HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você cometeu um pequeno erro, quando declarou o controller você usou `ng-controller="PageController as pc"` e na hora de usar a propriedade você setou o valor no $scope, ou seja, você ta settando em um lugar e tentando ler do outro.

Altere seu controller da seguinte forma:

```
var vm = this;
vm = "Sidenav";
```

Isso resolve seu problema. Dessa forma o valor está sendo settado no controller e não mais no `$scope.`

Você pode ler mais sobre isso [aqui](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers).